# How to display a certain portion of a site depending on a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a javascript variable "is_valid"

If the variable is 1, I'd like to display:

```
<div>It's valid!</div> ...and a big chunk of other code
```

Otherwise...

```
<div>NOT valid</div>...and a big chunk of other code
```

I do NOT want to use INNERHTML. I want to do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(is_valid == 1){
</script>
    It's valid!
<script type="text/javascript">
    }else{
</script>
    It's not valid
<script type="text/javascript">
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Generally, the way you do it is to put both options in the page, then show one and hide the other. You're approaching this from a server-side perspective and wanting to put <% %> tags around stuff, which works when you're outputting once and never changing again, but it doesn't work as well in the client-side perspective where things can change at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the code in an element that you can show or hide. Example:

```
<div id="Valid">
  <div>It's valid!</div> ...and a big chunk of other code
</div>
<div id="Invalid">
   <div>NOT valid</div>...and a big chunk of other code
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('Valid').style.display = (is_valid == 1 ? 'block' : 'none');
document.getElementById('Invalid').style.display = (is_valid == 1 ? 'none' : 'block');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have:

```
<div id="isvalid">It's valid!</div>
<div id="isnotvalid">NOT valid!</div>
... blah blah ...
```

Then, in your JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("isvalid").style.display = is_valid ? "" : "none";
document.getElementById("isnotvalid").style.display = is_valid ? "none" : "";
```

Or, if you use jQuery:

```
$("#isvalid").toggle(isvalid);
$("#isnotvalid").toggle(!isvalid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you already have the content on the page and just want to toggle visibility, you can do the following.

**HTML**

```
<div id="valid_section">....</div>
<div id="invalid_section">....</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("valid_section").style.display   = is_valid ? ""     : "none";
document.getElementById("invalid_section").style.display = is_valid ? "none" : "";
```